# Recursive 'Make Immutable' function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability

I have a data structure which consists of lists, ints and strings, nested arbitarily. For example:

```
[ "data", [ 1, "file", [], [1,2] ], 3 ]
```

I want to index a `dict` using objects like this, but I can't because python complains they are not immutable (which is true). I am suprised to find that there doesn't seem to be a generic recursive 'make immutable' function. Does such a function exist? Is there a good reason why not? And how should I work around this problem?

Comment: The immutable equivalent of a list is a tuple. There is no generic function for the conversion, but it is easy enough to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's quite an unusual and unwieldy data structure to want to use as a dictionary key, and leads me to wonder whether this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Leaving that observation to one side ... for the specific kind of structure you specify, containing nothing but lists (mutable) and strings and ints (immutable), a recursive function to convert all the lists to tuples is straightforward:

```
def tuplify(value):
    if isinstance(value, list):
        return tuple(tuplify(x) for x in value)
    else:
        return value
```

... and works as expected:

```
>>> tuplify(['data', [1, 'file', [], [1, 2]], 3])
('data', (1, 'file', (), (1, 2)), 3)
```

There's no solution for freezing arbitrary mutable objects, though. Some years ago, a [freeze protocol](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0351/) for Python was proposed and rejected, but even if it had been accepted you'd have had to rely on every mutable object you were likely to come across implementing a `__freeze__()` method for it to work.

Comment: Thanks.

My exact problem is that I have an existing function which takes a data structure as I describe (in practice it represents a tree), performs an expensive calculation (which can take 10 minutes), and returns a result.

This function is functional -- it always returns the same output given a particular input. Therefore an obvious thing to do is to wrap it in a cache, to store previous calls and their return value. And the obvious (to me) way to store this cache is as a dict, hence the need for an immutable representation of my data structure.